# Error while trying to sort grid component in vaadin flow

Tags: java, sorting, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

I am getting this error when I try to sort the grid programmatically:

```
grid.sort(List.of(  
        new GridSortOrder<>(grid.getColumnByKey("Νο"), SortDirection.ASCENDING),
        new GridSortOrder<>(grid.getColumnByKey("επίθετο"), SortDirection.ASCENDING)
));
```

The error:

> Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid$Column.getInternalId()" because the return value of "com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.GridSortOrder.getSorted()" is null

Is it because I use Greek characters in `Grid` columns? Do you know any solution or workaround?

Comment: I also tried with column names in English but I get the same error.

Answer (score 4):

In order to call `grid.getColumnByKey()` you need to set the key for each column. This works okay:

```
    final String COL1 = "Νο";
    final String COL2 = "επίθετο";

    Grid<SomeBean> grid = new Grid<>();

    grid.addColumn(SomeBean::getId).setHeader("Column 1").setKey(COL1);
    grid.addColumn(SomeBean::getName).setHeader("Column 2").setKey(COL2);
     
    grid.sort(List.of(  
        new GridSortOrder<>(grid.getColumnByKey(COL1), SortDirection.ASCENDING),
        new GridSortOrder<>(grid.getColumnByKey(COL2), SortDirection.ASCENDING)
    ));
```